# SharedPreferences Data spreads on every Fragment

Tags: java, android, database, android-fragments, gson

I got a problem with the date of my SharedPreferences. I am using 5 Fragment wher you can dynamically add item to a RecyclerView. The Problem is that when ever I save my data on a particular fragment and reload the app the value that has been saved loads into every single Fragment of mine.It actually save the data to the Fragment it is on.I am using Gson to save my ArrayList of items

This is my Fragment (Fragment0 from 5 in total, the others are just copied and refactored)

```
package com.example.barryblack;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class FragmentPage0 extends Fragment {

private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private EditText editTask;
ArrayList<MyItem> items;
private Button insertbtn;
private Button stateButton;
private TextView taskText;
private String task;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    CreateExampleList();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment0, container, false);

    loadData();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(500);
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    taskText = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
    insertbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_insert);
    editTask = view.findViewById(R.id.editTask);
    stateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_button);

    insertbtn.setEnabled(false);
    editTask.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String taskInput = editTask.getText().toString().trim();
            insertbtn.setEnabled(!taskInput.isEmpty());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            task = editTask.getText().toString().trim();

        }
    });

    insertbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InsertItem();
            SaveData();
            editTask.setText(null);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void SaveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared 
preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    editor.putString("task list", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared 
preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    items = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (items == null) {
        items = new ArrayList();
    }

}

public void InsertItem() {

    items.add(new MyItem(task, stateButton));
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());
}

private void CreateExampleList() {
    items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
}

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, 
ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        items.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        SaveData();

    }
};

}
```

This is my Adapter. I think the problem is inside the `OnCreateViewHolder` but im not quiet sure

```
package com.example.barryblack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<MyItem> mExampleList;

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView;
    private EditText topicName;
    public Button mButton;
    private int clicks = 1;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    public static final String TOPIC = "topic";
    public static final String CLICKS = "clicks";

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
        mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_button);
        topicName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicks++;

                if (clicks % 2 == 0) {
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_green);
                }else
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_red);
            }
        });
    }

}

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<MyItem> exampleList) {

    mExampleList = exampleList;
}

@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);

    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mTextView.setText(currentItem.getTaskText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: i think you need to use different key for every fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your fragments. So every fragment has his own `SharedPreferences`

```
 private static final String SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_A = "fragmentA";
 private static final String SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_B = "fragmentB";
...

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_A , MODE_PRIVATE);
```